# Rails 3 - Script doesn't run after cap:deploy

Tags: deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano

I want to run few commands when i start application on server.

So, i wrote such script in **config/deploy.rb**:

```
desc "Start sphinx" 
  task :start_sphinx, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{current_path} && bundle install --without development test && bundle install --deployment && chmod 777 -R #{current_path}/tmp/ && rake thinking_sphinx:configure && rake thinking_sphinx:start"
  end
```

But when i print

```
$ cap deploy
```

It doesn't work. So, please, tell me what is wrong!

Here is log from terminal:

```
$ cap deploy
  * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git://github.com/Loremaster/sample_app.git master"
    command finished in 367ms
  * executing "if [ -d /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard b5073e9b9aefd98873489bb6e97249593ea1a978 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q git://github.com/Loremaster/sample_app.git /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/shared/cached-copy && cd /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy b5073e9b9aefd98873489bb6e97249593ea1a978; fi"
    servers: ["188.127.224.136"]
Password: 
    [188.127.224.136] executing command
    command finished in 3070ms
    copying the cached version to /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835
  * executing "cp -RPp /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/shared/cached-copy /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835 && (echo b5073e9b9aefd98873489bb6e97249593ea1a978 > /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835/REVISION)"
    servers: ["188.127.224.136"]
    [188.127.224.136] executing command
    command finished in 49970ms
  * executing `deploy:finalize_update'
  * executing "chmod -R g+w /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835"
    servers: ["188.127.224.136"]
    [188.127.224.136] executing command
    command finished in 1023ms
  * executing "rm -rf /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835/log /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835/public/system /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835/tmp/pids &&\\\n      mkdir -p /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835/public &&\\\n      mkdir -p /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835/tmp &&\\\n      ln -s /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/shared/log /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835/log &&\\\n      ln -s /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/shared/system /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835/public/system &&\\\n      ln -s /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/shared/pids /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835/tmp/pids"
    servers: ["188.127.224.136"]
    [188.127.224.136] executing command
    command finished in 150ms
  * executing "find /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835/public/images /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835/public/stylesheets /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835/public/javascripts -exec touch -t 201201251659.26 {} ';'; true"
    servers: ["188.127.224.136"]
    [188.127.224.136] executing command
 ** [out :: 188.127.224.136] find: `/vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835/public/images': No such file or directory
 ** [out :: 188.127.224.136] find: `/vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835/public/stylesheets': No such file or directory
 ** [out :: 188.127.224.136] find: `/vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835/public/javascripts': No such file or directory
    command finished in 566ms
  * executing `deploy:symlink'
  * executing "rm -f /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/current && ln -s /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125165835 /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/current"
    servers: ["188.127.224.136"]
    [188.127.224.136] executing command
    command finished in 56ms
 ** transaction: commit
  * executing `deploy:restart'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' touch /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/current/tmp/restart.txt"
    servers: ["188.127.224.136"]
    [188.127.224.136] executing command
    command finished in 163ms
```

Comment: Can you post what happens when you try, besides that it doesn't work?

Comment: @PinnyM I posted my log from terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the callback.  For example, if you wanted to run your script after the code has been updated, you can use an after callback like

```
after "deploy:update_code", "start_sphinx"
```

For more info on callbacks, check out the [callbacks rdoc](http://rubydoc.info/github/capistrano/capistrano/master/Capistrano/Configuration/Callbacks)